# SwiftUI clipped Image is not really clipped

Tags: swiftui

In iOS 15, the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack{ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self) {Text("Item\($0)")}}
      }
      Image(systemName: "clock").resizable()
        .padding(.top, -50).frame(height: 50)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .clipped()
        .onTapGesture {print("good")}
    }
  }
}
```

It happens that the `ScrollView` can't be scrolled because the bottom Image overlays it.
How can we scroll the `ScrollView`?

Comment: What exactly is the UI you are trying to accomplish? Do you want the image behind the scrollview? A mock up would be helpful here.

Comment: I want to take an inner part of an image, so I pad by a negative value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clock view is eating the taps.  You need to make the clock ignore taps by adding this:

```
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

like this:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack{ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self) {Text("Item\($0)")}}
      }
      Image(systemName: "clock").resizable()
        .padding(.top, -50).frame(height: 50)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .clipped()
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is helpful, but how about we want to tap the Image to do some action?

Comment: it seems `.allowsHitTesting(false).contentShape(Rectangle()).onTapGesture {print("good")}` can do it.